# Cleaning the camera roll from my mom's iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, camera

I'm trying to clean the gallery of the iPhone, I'm sending the images that I already put in the computer to the trash.
But the pics still are in the phone.

I'm an android user, so i don't know if the process is different for iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to go to the "Recently Deleted" album and remove them as necessary if your iOS version > 8.1.

To remove all photos in "Recently Deleted", tap "Select" at the top and then "Delete All" at the bottom.

Comment: Great!
It worked.
Thank you very much!